# Error accessing the class having hyphen(-) separated names in html file using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the data of popular english movies on [Hotstar](http://www.hotstar.com/movies/languages/english/)

I downloaded the html source code and I am doing this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
page_soup = soup(open('hotstar.html'),'html.parser')
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 ng-scope"}) 
container = containers[0]
# To get video link
container.div.hs-cards-directive.article.a
```

I am getting an error at this point:

```
NameError: name 'cards' is not defined
```

These are the first few lines of the html file:

```
<div bindonce="" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 ng-scope" ng-repeat="slides in gridcardData">
<hs-cards-directive cdata="slides" class="ng-isolate-scope" renderingdone="shownCard()">
    <article class="card show-card" ng-class="{'live-sport-card':isLiveSportCard, 'card-active':btnRemoveShow,'tounament-tray-card':record.isTournament}" ng-click="cardeventhandler({cardrecord:record})" ng-init="init()" pdata="record" removecard="removecard" watched="watched">
        <a href="http://www.hotstar.com/movies/step-up-revolution/1770016594" ng-href="/movies/step-up-revolution/1770016594" restrict-anchor="">
```

Please help me out!
I am using Python 3.6.3 on Windows.

Comment: My initial reaction would be to strip the "-" from the source where you need to so that you can use the syntax you want. I don't know if bs4 has the option of indexing differently, but if so that would be option 2(similiar to pandas df['hs-cards'] as opposed to df.hs-cards)

Comment: Hyphens cannot be part of an identifier (name) in Python. It parses `container.div.hs-cards-directive-article-a` as the mathematical expression `container.div.hs - cards - directive.article.a`, and the first problem it finds there is that there's no variable named `cards`.

Comment: Meanwhile, instead of giving us the first few lines of the HTML file, turn it into a [mcve] that we can actually test against. That often just means closing all the tags at the end, but it isn't always quite that trivial, so make sure you can reproduce your error with the sample input before you paste it.

Comment: Actually, in this case, you should be able to just ask BS4 to `print` that `container` node and get a complete example.

Comment: I want to create a csv file containing the titles, video links, thumbnail icons and category of each listing.

Answer (score 3):

As (loosely) explained in the [Going down](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#going-down) section of the docs, the `tag.descendant` syntax is just a convenient shortcut for `tag.find('descendant')`.

That shortcut can't be used in cases where you have tags whose names aren't valid Python identifiers.<sup>1</sup> (Also in cases where you have tags whose names collide with methods of BS4 itself, like a `<find>` tag.)

---

Python identifiers can only have letters, digits, and underscores, not hyphens. So, when you write this:

```
container.div.hs-cards-directive.article.a
```

… python parses it like this mathematical expression:

```
container.div.hs - cards - directive.article.a
```

BeautifulSoup's `div` node has no descendant named `hs`, but that's fine; it just returns `None`. But then you try to subtract `cards` from that `None`, and you get a `NameError`.

---

Anyway, the only solution in this case is to not use the shortcut and call `find` explicitly:

```
container.div.find('hs-cards-directive').article.a
```

Or, if it makes sense for your use case, you can just skip down to `article`, because the shortcut finds any descendants, not just direct children:

```
container.div.article.a
```

But I don't think that's appropriate in your case; you want articles only under specific child nodes, not all possible articles, right?

---

<sub>1. Technically, it *is* actually possible to use the shortcut, it's just not a shortcut anymore. If you understand what `getattr(container.div, 'hs-cards-directive').article.a` means, then you can write that and it will work… but obviously `find` is going to be more readable and easier to understand.</sub>